# Customized floor/ceiling for dates in R

Tags: r, datetime, intervals, floor, ceil

say I have a date range from `start` to `end` where `start <- as.Date(2009-11-05), end <- as.Date(2009-12-17)`.

I want a function that essentially acts as a customized floor/ceiling and returns a date interval such that the lower bound is the first date of the form 'yyyy-mm-23' smaller or equal to '2009-11-05' and the upper bound is the first date greater or equal to '2009-12-17' and of the form 'yyyy-mm-22'.

In the above example, the function should return the interval ('2009-10-23, 2009-12-22).

I've tried using seq.Date and using the length function on it but it seems tedious and I wonder if there is a faster solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be another approach to try. Using `lubridate` create new start and end dates, substituting the 23rd and 22nd. Then, if the start date precedes the 23rd, subtract a month. Likewise, if the end date exceeds the 22nd, add a month.

```
start <- as.Date("2009-11-05")
end <- as.Date("2009-12-17")

library(lubridate)

my_fun <- function(start, end) {
  new_start <- start
  day(new_start) <- 23
  new_end <- end
  day(new_end) <- 22
  if (day(start) < 23) new_start = new_start %m-% months(1)
  if (day(end) > 22) new_end = new_end %m+% months(1)
  return(interval(new_start, new_end))
}

my_fun(start, end)
```

**Output**

```
[1] 2009-10-23 UTC--2009-12-22 UTC
```

---

**Edit**: In the comment, the reference day of the month could be greater than 28, which could result in an invalid date. To consider this possibility, one approach is to use the `clock` package which can handle an invalid date (e.g., Feb. 31), and then resolve to closest day.

```
start <- as.Date("2009-03-30")
end <- as.Date("2009-12-17")

reference <- 31

library(lubridate)
library(clock)

my_fun <- function(start, end, reference) {
  new_start <- set_day(year_month_day(year(start), month(start)), reference)
  new_end <- set_day(year_month_day(year(end), month(end)), reference)
  if (day(start) < reference) new_start = add_months(new_start, -1) 
  if (day(end) > reference) new_end = add_months(new_end, 1)
  new_start = invalid_resolve(new_start, invalid = "previous") 
  new_end = invalid_resolve(new_end, invalid = "next")
  return(c(new_start, new_end))
}

my_fun(start, end, reference)
```

**Output**

```
[1] "2009-02-28" "2009-12-31"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Nice and simple, avoiding the creation of date sequences with seq.Date

Comment: What about the case where we have the 31st as reference day and start date is say 2009-02-28? We surely can’t set day(new_start) <- 31 then, but we want new_start to be 2009-02-28?

Comment: @Lollo231000 If you can have a "reference" day that is greater than 28, you can use the `clock` package and then resolve invalid dates. See second example in the edited answer above. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a function that works like that, but I would code something like this:

### Code

```
custom_bound <- function(date, type, ref_day){
  
  obs_day <- lubridate::day(date)

  if(type == "lower"){aux <- -1}
  
  if(type == "upper"){aux <- 1}      
  
  while(obs_day != ref_day ){
    
    date <- date + days(aux)
    
    obs_day <- lubridate::day(date)
    
  }
  
  return(date)
  
}
```

### Output

```
> custom_bound(date = as.Date("2009-11-05"),type = "lower",ref_day = 23)
[1] "2009-10-23"

> custom_bound(date = as.Date("2009-12-17"),type = "upper",ref_day = 22)
[1] "2009-12-22"
```